# Oracle query translating encrypted column values incorrectly in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle, encryption, vb6, oledb

We have a vb6 application that creates users and saves an encrypted password into our oracle database using our own encryption methods. We then have a visual basic web service that queries this table in order to validate a user's log in. This is where the issue is coming in.

For example:

- a Password is saved in the database as [nµ}r r« ry kk]
- the vb.net application then queries this password and it is returned as [nµ}r?r«?ry?kk]

As I understand it, it's because of the OleDBConnection we're using which is incorrectly translating the character set used in Oracle. My question is, is there any way to work around this issue so that the value returned from the database matches what is in the database?

Comment: Which OleDB provider do you use? The Microsoft or the Oracle?

Comment: What is the character set of your database? Check with `SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit we use oracle provider, this is our connection string: Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=[Password];User ID=[User];Data Source=[database]

Comment: Another question: Do you store encrypted password as text values? If yes, that is a bad design, because encryption may result in byte values which do not represent a valid character (e.g. `x06` which means  **ACK**nowledge) you cannot enter by keyboard and which are not stored in database.

Comment: unfortunately the design of the database was done very very long ago and the entire thing is horrid, but we cannot change it. It's stored as a varchar column. The characte rset is WE8ISO8859P1

Comment: No, `MSDAORA` is the Microsoft provider. This one is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle) for ages and does not support Unicode. Use the Oracle Provider `OraOLEDB.Oracle`

Comment: Ah, thanks Wernfried. I will give it a try.

Comment: You also should consider to save the encrypted password as [BASE64](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string in order to avoid all these problems.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I tried your suggestion and updated my connection string to Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=[Password];User ID=[UserID];Data Source=[Database]. I can see a difference in the encrypted values, however, it still isn't reading the value correctly. Thanks for the suggestion though, I will continue hunting for the answer.

Comment: Did you try to save your string as Base64? Your entire design is really bad, you will not be able to fix it just by changing a few lines of code. According documentation from Oracle you have to change character set of your database to Al32utf8

Comment: I'd love to change the design as it's not mine, however, we cannot change the inherited code.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling and many helpful answers, my issue turned out to be the related to two things:

1. The version of oracle the application uses could only properly decrypt data using oracle 8i and not the latest oracle. This is a limitation imposed by the fact that many of the clients still use an old setup. Data encrypted with oracle 8i client would not be decrypted correctly with the oracle 10 client.
2. Along with the version of oracle, the client type - 32 bit vs 64 bit - was an important distinguishing factor for decrypting. For this scenario, I needed the 32 bit client in order to use the oracle provider suggested by Wernfried Domscheit that would correctly decrypt and encrypt data as expected.

So in short, the character sets used by oracle 8i 32 bit and the character sets used by the latest oracle 64 bit will not be the same for ansi characters using methods such as "Chr" in vb.net .